# How to be able to tell if a molecule will react via SN1 or SN2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

I've been having a lot of issues with a question.

2 compounds, (1-chloro-2,2-dimethylpropyl)benzene and (1-chloro-2-methylpropyl)benzene react with EtOH in water.

It asks to classify the reaction mechanism for each and to then go on and explain why (1-chloro-2-methylpropyl)benzene has a much faster relative rate.

I am having major issues with the question, because I just cannot tell where there are any major differences between molecules which could make a difference. Both of them have a benzene ring, but this stabilises both the transition state *and* the carbocation intermediate so will favour both SN1 and SN2. Both reactions are done in the exact same solvent with the same nucleophile.

The only differences I can spot is that in (1-chloro-2,2-dimethylpropyl)benzene, there will be more stabilisation due to the inductive effect and hence it will favour SN1. But this does not help with determining the mechanism for (1-chloro-2-methylpropyl)benzene.

Any help will be much appreciated. Many thanks :)

Comment: I think you need to consider steric factors when thinking about the relative reaction rates

Answer (score 4):

Factors affecting S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism:

> 1. **Weak** nucleophile / base and Good leaving group.
> 2. More **steric hindrance**.
> 3. Polar **protic** solvent should be used.

Factors affecting S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism:

> 1. **Strong** nucleophile / base and Good leaving group.
> 2. Less **steric hindrance**.
> 3. Polar **aprotic** solvent should be used.

---

Coming back to your problem. Actually, both of the compounds can go through S<sub>N</sub>1 or S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism as the carbon linked with $\ce{Cl}$ is a **secondary carbon**. But, as you mentioned that you're using $\ce{EtOH}$, and you should know that $\ce{EtOH}$ is little basic, almost neutral, therefore, we can say that now, both of the compounds will go through S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism (Remember, the **first** point of S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism, i.e., **weak base**).

Now, the question is if both the compounds will follow S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism, then which will react faster. For this, we will have a look at the S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism:

[image: SN1 mechanism]

> Step 1: Leaving of the (-X) group
>
> Step 2: Weak nucleophile attacks from either side
>
> Step 3: Substitution product formed (Inversion or retention, based on
>   the step 2)

So, our concern is only the step 2.

Note that, rate of reaction in step 2 depends on **steric hindrance** in your case. So, let's have a look at the structure of (1-chloro-2,2-dimethylpropyl)benzene and (1-chloro-2-methylpropyl)benzene:

[image]
[image]

The Carbon with red dot is the point where $\ce{EtOH}$ will attack after the (-Cl) will leave.

Now, on comparing the both the compounds, you will notice that in the first compounds there is **greater steric hindrance** as compared to the second compound. And, that's the reason why second compound will react faster than the first one.

**Conclusion**:

> (1-chloro-2-methylpropyl)benzene will **react faster** than
>   (1-chloro-2,2-dimethylpropyl)benzene due to **less steric hindrance**
>   around the carbon that is directly attached to aromatic ring (i.e.,
>   the carbon with red dot).
>
> And, both of the compounds will go through **S<sub>N</sub>1
>   mechanism** due to **presence of $\ce{EtOH}$**.